# How can I scale an image in a datagridview c#

Tags: c#, image, datagridview

I have a database query that returns a DataSet which I then use to populate a DataGridView:

```
DataSet ds = CapsDbUtils.GetSamples(sampleIds);
dgvSample.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

One column (10) contains pictures and these are displayed in the grid but I need to scale them to fit. I know that this is possible if I explicitly create an image column:

```
imageCol.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch;
```

Does anyone know how do I cast the existing column to an imageColumn so that I can set this property?

Comment: Show us the code for the column.

Comment: Have you considered "manually" adding the `DataGridViewImageColumn` to the grid? Example, manually add the `DataGridViewImageColumn` through code or the designer… Then set its `ImageLayout` property to “Stretch”. Then set the columns `DataPropertyName` to the name of the `Image` column in the `DataTable`. This should mate the manually added column to the `Image` column in the table when the grids data source is set.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I think that this would require me to hand-craft the columns in the grid and map them to the DataSet table.  I'm sure that there must be a way of casting the column type but I just don't know how to do it.  If I don't find out, I'll resort to the hand-crafted approach.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code to cast a Grids column to a `DataGridViewImageColumn`… obviously, the column needs to be an actual `Image` type column.

```
try {
  DataGridViewImageColumn imgCol = (DataGridViewImageColumn)dataGridView1.Columns["ImageColName"];
  imgCol.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch;
}
catch (Exception ex) {
  MessageBox.Show("Error casting column to image column: " + ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Thanks JohnG - exactly what I was after!  Works a dream!